# GitHub ssh key audit with no approve button

Tags: github, ssh, ssh-keys

Today I added an SSH key on to my GitHub account. When I try and clone a repo to that machine, I get the following error:

[image]

I visited the `/settings/keys` GitHub page but I do not see an "Approve" button next to the key I just added.

[image]

The guide [here](https://help.github.com/articles/reviewing-your-ssh-keys/) from GitHub says there should be an "Approve" button. When I try to refresh the keys page, sometimes the newly added key disappears, then sometimes it reappears. I have tried deleting it and adding it back, but I get the same error.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a new key? Try generating a new one ssh-keygen, and add to your ~/.ssh/config file

Comment: GitHub is currently [recovering from a major outage](https://status.github.com/messages) and several web-facing features are currently disabled. Try again later in the day once they're back on their feet.

Comment: Ahh.. Good catch @Chris. That's probably it... Thanks!

Comment: Just tried to clone again and now it works. Must've been the outage issue. Thanks again!